# Can mongoexport be used to export images stored in binary format in mongodb

Tags: python, image, mongodb, csv

I am using mongoexport to export mongodb data which also has Image data in Binary format.

Export is done in csv format.

I tried to read image data from csv file into python and tried to store as in Image File in .jpg format on disk.

But it seems that, data is corrupt and image is not getting stored.

Has anybody come across such situation or resolved similar thing ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

One thing to watch out for is an arbitrary 2MB BSON Object size limit in several of 10gen's implementations. You might have to denormalize your image data and store it across multiple objects.

Comment: images are well below 2MB. There are of KB sizes. I think, when images are stored in csv file by mongoexport (as binary data) and read back in Python as binary data, it's getting corrupt.

Comment: I just wanted to know if it's the correct way to do it (using mongoexport) or am I doing something incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Depending how you stored the data, it may be prefixed with 4 bytes of size.  Are the corrupt exports 4 bytes/GridFS chunk longer than you'd expect?

Comment: yes .. sizes differ by considerable margin. May be when data is converted to csv format it's padded with extra information.